# $2 \times2$ Rubik's cube

Tags: group-theory, rubiks-cube

Let the face of the $2 \times2$ Rubik's cube be defined as the ordered quadruple of colors of it's pieces in a fixed direction (let's say counterclockwise). Does the set of $6$ quadruples define a unique cube state? Of course the state has to be solvable and color scheme of the solved state is fixed.

At first I thought this is trivially true, but I failed to prove it and found that it's far from trivial.

Comment: " ordered quadruple of colors of it's pieces in a fixed direction (let's say counterclockwise). Does the set of 6 quadruples define a unique cube state?" I understand nothing of that

Comment: You mean, assume we know the state up to permutation and rotation of faces, does this determine the state (up to rotations of the solid cube)?

Comment: Let $S$ be the set of colorings of the $2$-cube. The group $(\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z)^6$ acts on $S$ by rotating each face, where a face here consists of just four squares, not the eight additional squares that are physically attached to them when you rotate the cube normally. Your question, if I understand it correctly, is whether or not it's true that each orbit has at most one valid Rubik's cube configuration. Have I reformulated your question correctly? If so, I'd be fairly surprised if that is true. I don't have a counterexample off the top of my head, though.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen exactly

Comment: There's just 3.6 million positions. Seems feasible to just number crunch this problem

Comment: @DustanLevenstein It's also allowed to swap 2 faces

Comment: Ah. So instead of $(\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z)^6$, you have some twisted product of that group with $S_6$. That makes me even more skeptical.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen you are probably right, but I don't know how to write a program, unfortunately I'm bad at programming.

Comment: why nobody wants to explain clearly his question ? it is so obvious that it is badly written... does he mean remembering only the 4 colors of each face, without remembering in which (spatial) order are the faces ?

Comment: Well, my friend spotted a counterexample, I just constructed it to check. So here it is, if you are familiar with the cube notation 
1: {U2 L B' L' B D B D' B' R' U F B L' U' B L' U2}   
2: {F U' F2 D' B U R' F' L D' R' U' L U B' D2 R' F}

Comment: @user1952009 I thought my explanation, together with the op's added caveat, was pretty clear. He means remembering the 4 colors of each face *in cyclic order*, but not remembering which face is where.

Comment: If we call the (multi?)set of faces in cyclic order the fingerprint of a cube state, then the (hopefully not so error-prone) program I just wrote tells me that the 3674160 states have only 3556086 different fingerprints. So, there are quite a few cases of states haring fingerprints

Comment: ... and it seems that the particularly symmetric "fingerprint" {blue-blue-white-white, blue-blue-white-white, red-red-orange-orange, red-red-orange-orange, yellow-yellow-green-green, yellow-yellow-green-green} holds the world-record with 16 matching states. -- There are also two states with two opposing faces "intact" and same fingerprint.

Comment: Wow, did I really miss that

Comment: I may find the time to create some graphics tomorrow and won't convert my comments to an answer before that (and won't at all if I find this question nicely answered by then)